# How to send msg.value to a payable func in solidity during a foundry test?

Tags: solidity

My Contract Code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {CarNFT} from "./CarNFT.sol";
// OrderManager contract

contract OrderManager {
    ... code

    function deposit() external payable onlyBuyer {
        // Buyer deposits funds
        require(msg.value == price, "Incorrect deposit amount");
    }

}
```

OrderManger.t.sol test file

```
function testDeposit() public {
        // Assuming startPrank, deal, and stopPrank functions work as expected
        vm.startPrank(buyer);
        vm.deal(buyer, 10 ether);

        // Ensure the buyer has the expected balance
        uint256 buyerBalanceBefore = address(buyer).balance;
        assertEq(buyerBalanceBefore, 10 ether);

        // Deposit into OrderManager contract
        orderM.deposit();

        // Ensure the balance of the OrderManager contract is updated
        uint256 contractBalance = orderM.getBalance();
        emit log_named_uint("Contract's balance is", contractBalance);
        assertEq(price, contractBalance);

        // Ensure the buyer's balance has been reduced by the deposited amount
        uint256 buyerBalanceAfter = address(buyer).balance;
        emit log_named_uint("Buyer's balance after deposit is", buyerBalanceAfter);
        assertEq(buyerBalanceBefore - price, buyerBalanceAfter);

        vm.stopPrank();
    }
```

If i want to send ETH in the calldata via msg.send what syntax do i use?

I am using Foundry as dev tool ; should i use Foundry cheatcodes for this purpose?

Kindly guide

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax here is

```js
orderM.deposit{value: 0.2 ether}()
```

or in general

```js
contractInstance.func{value: msg.value (value in ether or wei; see below)}(func args)
```

if in foundry msg.send can be specified in (0.2 ether) otherwise send in wei (200000000000000000)

Answer (score 0):

Use: orderM.deposit {value: 0.2 ether} ()

You don't need to use cheatcodes the syntax should work